# ¿Cómo se pronuncia "realpolitik" en español?

Tags: sustantivos, pronunciación, extranjerismos

Nos descubre @blonfu en [el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49764043#49764043) la voz *realpolitik*, recogida en el DLE:

> **[realpolitik](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VHa297j)**
>
> Del al. *Realpolitik*.
>
> 1. f. Política basada en criterios pragmáticos, al margen de ideologías.

Lo que me sorprende de esta palabra es que está recogida como una voz ya adaptada al español, dado que la entrada no está en cursiva como otros extranjerismos crudos. Por tanto, entiendo que se debe pronunciar tal y como se escribe, y que por tanto es aguda ("realpolitík").

¿Es así? Cuando la he leído, al ver que era un extranjerismo he pronunciado la parte de "real" como si fuera en inglés, y la parte de "politik" como si fuera llana, a pesar de no llevar tilde. ¿Cómo se debe pronunciar esta palabra?

Answer (score 7):

La palabra **realpolitik**, tal como se puede ver en el extracto del DLE que has puesto, proviene del alemán, no del inglés.
Por suerte, la pronunciación del alemán es bastante parecida a la del español*, y por tanto la palabra **se pronuncia como se escribe: `/realpolitík/`, con acento en la última sílaba** (aunque no es infrecuente escucharla pronunciada como si fuera llana, aplicando a "-politik" el mismo acento que a "política").

Entiendo, además, que por ese motivo se ha podido incorporar como extranjerismo adaptado sin cambiar la grafía de la misma.

<sub>* Las vocales A, E, I, O, U y las consonantes F, K, L, M, N, P, T se pronuncian igual. La R es más gutural en el norte, pero en el sur (Baviera, Austria) es más parecida a la nuestra. Hay [algunas diferencias](https://www.gramatica-alemana.es/curso-aleman/leccion1-pronunciacion/) más, claro, pero ninguna de ellas aplica a la palabra en cuestión.</sub>